# Screw modifier not working perfectly

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

Has anyone had problems like this?
just previously the modifier works fine but just take look at this 
[image]

[image]
:(

Comment: Have you applied the rotation and scale?

Comment: It looks like Z-fighting. Make sure you have no duplicate vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you apply any previous transformation to your curves/mesh (in *Object Mode*) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, in my case, X axis was scaled to zero so naturally it became flat.

I did not realized this all the while thinking the only transform I did was in edit mode.

Hope that someone find this helpful as well :)